# Infrared Reciver doesn't work properly after the first signal

Tags: arduino-uno, ir, infrared

i'm trying to play a passive buzzer with an IR reciver

**My Code**

```
#include <IRremote.h>
IRrecv irrecv(10);
decode_results results;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(11, OUTPUT);//buzzer
  irrecv.enableIRIn();//Ir reciver at pin 10
}

int cmdex = 0;

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  if(irrecv.decode(&results)){
    cmdex = 1;
    Serial.println(results.value);
    unsigned long data = results.value;
    switch(data){
      case 0xFF30CF:
        noTone(11);
        tone(11, 1056);
        break;
      case 0xFF18E7:
        noTone(11);
        tone(11, 571);
        break;
      case 0xFF6897:
        noTone(11);
        break;
    }
    irrecv.resume();
  }
}
```

**Issue**

My problem is that if i use any button instead of 1 (FF30CF) 0 (FF6897) or 2 (FF18E7) the serilal port give me the right data, then when i pusch 1 the buzzer starts to play but when i push another button, the data keep changing at every push.

**Serial Output**
FF10EF *(here I push 4)*

FF38C7 *(here I push 5)*

FF5AA5 *(here I push 6)*

FF30CF *(here I finally push 1 and the buzzer starts to play)*

*(then I push 3 times 0, but the output is different from the expected FF6897 and the buzzer doesn't stop)*

D965AA42

EB670632

AB03A967

**Note**

- I'm using the IRremote.h library

Comment: does IRremote use Timer2 used by tone()?

Comment: as per @Juraj comment ... please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62832918/function-tone-and-irremote

Comment: Ok thanks, how ca I solve the timer issue?